# Cannot open specific *.lib file

Tags: c++, static, linkage, lib

I have a small project - https://github.com/Eugene-Golubev/CSNS-SoftON-Hack/

Some features separated from main code in 4 little static libraries: anti-re, easy-hwid, easy-packer, and softon-socket. Everything is totally OK when I build solution with 'Release' configuration. But if I try to build 'Debug' (x86, btw) configuration, I get errors looks like "cannot open file 'softon-socket_x86d.lib'". Though everything is OK about others libraries. They are linked without any problems, I guess. Also all built libraries are stored together in 'client/lib' folder, and that folder contains 'softon-socket_x86d.lib'. Sooo, I don't really understand what's going on

Comment: What build system do you use? cmake? visual studio?

Comment: @Lasersköld, MSVS.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions?